# how to find earliest date and latest date from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want to perform email functionality in my app.In that in subject i have to add earliest date in database and latest date in database.so how can i get earliest date and latest date from database?I have database fields like 
     EntryDate which is datetime datatype
     Amount 
    LastEdited with datetime datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a query to sort date..like

```
SELECT TaskDate FROM MyTask Order By TaskDate limit 1
SELECT TaskDate FROM MyTask Order By TaskDate Desc limit 1
```

First one will give u oldest date and second will give the latest date.
hope this will help u out.