# How do I find the earliest date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am working with a Postgres table that has a field named `first_contact_date` where it is of type date.  I am using the [the mm/dd/yyyy representation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) of a date.
My query works correctly as written but it orders literally by month.

```
SELECT first_contact_date 
FROM schema.table 
ORDER BY first_contact_date
```

For example "10/3/2016" would go after "1/2/2017", even though in a date sense, it should be "1/2/2017" that goes after "10/3/2016".

I have looked at

1. [How to find the earliest and latest date from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357438/how-to-find-earliest-date-and-latest-date-from-database), but its too vague and I am using an order by already.
2. [SQL ordering by earliest date in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946488/sql-ordering-by-earliest-date-in-group), but I am using a different format.
3. [How do I return the record with the earliest date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499063/how-do-i-return-the-record-with-the-earliest-date), ditto with number 2

and

4. [PostgreSQL query where date oldest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203246/postgresql-query-where-date-oldest), but this limits it to one year

How to I structure the query so that the earliest date from a calendar perspective is returned?

Comment: cast it to date for ordering `order by first_contact_date::date`

Comment: Typing in:

SELECT first_contact_date
FROM schema.table
order by first_contact_date::date

Gives:
 Error message:
invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Comment: The `Error message: invalid input syntax for type date: ""` implies that your column is **not** of type date. Maybe you should add your table definition plus some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract interval starting from beginning of year and order by it:

```
SELECT first_contact_date-date_trunc('year',first_contact_date), first_contact_date
FROM schema.table 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Edit: Long years might not work properly as duration starting from begining of year might differ after February.

This is a bit dirty, but will work correctly also for long years:

```
    SELECT to_char(first_contact_date,'MM')::int*100+to_char(first_contact_date,'DD')::int datenum
FROM schema.table 
ORDER BY 1;
```